# how to always have a 40-70 characters wide page? scren, mobile, print

Tags: css, mobile, readability, typography

How to balance a decent font-size regardless of the media (small vertical phone screen or full page printing) and a comfortable 40~80 char per lines using the current CSS best practices?

I think I know the drill for regular screens, set body's font-size to some percentage, mark your main content element with width being 70em and min-width 40em...

but then, i know nothing about the accepted standards for mobile and print for this problem.

All my search attempts take me to (now) futile discussions from 2002~2011 about the benefits of [em,pixel,%,pt] over the other...

Answer (score 5):

```
body {
  min-width: 16em;
  min-width: 40ch;
  max-width: 28em;
  max-width: 70ch;
}
```

Use the `ch` unit for “width of a character”, and back it up with a setting in `em` units, with a numeric value that is about 40% of the desired number of characters.

The `em` unit means the size of the font. For texts in Latin letters, this is about 40% of the average width of characters, maybe a little more.

The `ch` unit means the width of the digit 0. It is generally the best available approximation for “average width of characters” in CSS. It is supported by modern browsers, but for less than modern browsers, set first the width in `em` units.

This answers the question in the heading of your message. The body of the message is vague and does not pose a question that could be addressed constructively.

Comment: one ch is 1/2 em for most fonts. but 1/2 em is widely implemented on every browser :) And what happens if the screen size is smaller than that? which fallback should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a page width relative to the character size would only make sense with a monotype font. Consider these two strings "iiiiiiiiii" and "WWWWWWWWWW" - both consist of 10 characters, but clearly require a container of different width!

You could play around with [`ex/em/ch` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS-2_Quick_Reference/Units), but they would not give you *full* control to accomplish what you're trying to do. Also: `ch` isn't even fully supported!

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/CpRMC/1/) sample

Comment: i don't have many lines full of i's and W's :) what i acomplish with my usual style is something that would read like this (if CSS wasn't implemented by the devil) `p { min-width: 20em; width: 40em; max-width: 80%; }` that gives me a nice 40-80 chars wide lines and do not use the full page. of course, i got that with a bunch of nested elements thanks to implementation.

Comment: @gcb: as soon as text starts wrapping (i.e. >1 line total), the largest allowed value will take precedence - paragraphs are blocks and need to have their dimensions set in that manner. You should be able to, depending on the font of choice, calculate an appropriate ratio to express *40 average character widths* in `em`; this came up suggesting an average of `1en = 1em/2` per character: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/news/glossary/ch6.htm

Comment: ex/em/ch units are just other names for the same problem you have with em. they are fixed pixel measures, just relative to some arbitrary character size. The only measure that would take intro account resolution is pt. but every single implementation (hum, and even the spec) made it useless... but back on topic. using em/en/ex/ch/etc you'd still need a way to set the font size relative to the screen real state.